# Access an Object created within another

Tags: java, design-patterns, scope, singleton, instance

I feel like my problem is simple but I do not know what to google for.

I have a run.java which essentially does this

```
public class run {
    //stuff
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //stuff     
        Solver solver = new Solver(body,seeds);
        solver.solve();
        LogTool.print("OUTPUT field of CLASS CREATED IN solver -- " + IDONTKNOWHOW,"notification");
    }
}
===========
public class Solver {
    //stuff
    public void solve() {
        //stuff
        GlobalState GLowestState = new GlobalState(this.Cur_state);
    }
}
```

So, how do I get to access GLowestState from within run.java ?

Does it make a difference that GLowestState is implemented with a Singleton?
I hope not.
I couldn't try anything because my IDE gives me an error for GLowestState.IDONTKNOWHOW.

==============

Update with more code:

```
public class run {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Voxel [][][] body = new Voxel[Config.xDIM][Config.yDIM][Config.zDIM];
         //stuff

        Solver solver = new Solver(body,seeds);        

        LogTool.print("Initialized Solver Object!","notification");
        LogTool.print("Beginning Annealing...","notification");
        looper.solveSA();
        GlobalState GLS = looper.getGLowestState();  <--- NPE here
        LogTool.print("GLC: " + looper.getGlobal_lowest_cost()+ " CURC: " + looper.getCur_cost(),"notification");
//        LogTool.print("GLS external: " + GLS,"notification");
        LogTool.print("SolveSA: Global Current Best Solution : " + looper.getGlobal_Lowest_state_string(),"notification");

=========
public class Looper {
    public static Voxel [][][] body; //Thobi hat das als ganz einfache Variable in seiner Loesermethode...nicht so OOP
    public static Seed[] seeds = new Seed[Config.SAnumberOfSeeds];
    public double[] Cur_state = new double[Config.SAnumberOfSeeds];
    public double[] New_state = new double[Config.SAnumberOfSeeds]; // Do I even need this ?
    public double[] Global_Lowest_state = new double[Config.SAnumberOfSeeds]; // Do I even need this ?
    GlobalState GLowestState;

    public Looper(Voxel [][][] body, Seed[] seeds) {
        this.temperature = Config.StartTemp;
        this.body = body;
        this.seeds = seeds;
                this.Cur_cost = Cur_cost;
                this.New_cost = New_cost;
                this.temperature = temperature;
                this.Cur_state = Cur_state;
                this.New_state = New_state;
                this.Global_lowest_cost = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                this.Global_Lowest_state = Global_Lowest_state;
    }

    public GlobalState getGLowestState() {
        return GLowestState;
    }



        for (int ab = 0; ab < Config.NumberOfMetropolisResets; ab++) {
            LogTool.print("==================== START CALC FOR OUTER ROUND " + ab + "=========================","notification");

            if (Config.SAverboselvl==1) {
                LogTool.print("SolveSA: Cur_State Read before Metropolis : A)" + Cur_state[0] + " B) " + Cur_state[1] + " C) " + Cur_state[2],"notification");
                LogTool.print("Debug: GLS get 1: " + this.getGlobal_Lowest_state_string(),"notification");
            }

            if (ab==0){
                this.initState();

                if (Config.SAverboselvl==1) {
                    LogTool.print("SolveSA: Cur_state after Initstate : A)" + Cur_state[0] + " B) " + Cur_state[1] + " C) " + Cur_state[2],"notification");
                }
            }

            setCur_cost(cost());

            /* [Newstate] with random dwelltimes */
            newState(); 
            if (Config.SAverboselvl==1) {
                LogTool.print("SolveSA: New State before Metropolis: A)" + New_state[0] + " B) " + New_state[1] + " C) " + New_state[2],"notification");
            }

            setNew_cost(cost());

            if (Config.SAverboselvl==1) {
                LogTool.print("SolveSA: New Cost : " + New_cost,"notification");
            }

            double random_double = RandGenerator.randDouble(0.01, 0.99);

            /**
                * MetropolisLoop
                * @param Config.NumberOfMetropolisRounds
             */

            for(int x=0;x<Config.NumberOfMetropolisRounds;x++) {   
    //            break;
    //            LogTool.print("SolveSA Iteration " + x + " Curcost " + Cur_cost + " Newcost " + New_cost,"notification");
               if ((Cur_cost - New_cost)>0) { // ? die Kosten

                   if (Config.SAverboselvl>1) {
                       LogTool.print("Fall 1","notification");
                   }

                   if (Config.SAdebug) {                      
                          LogTool.print("SolveSA: Metropolis NewCost : " + this.getNew_cost(),"notification");
                          LogTool.print("SolveSA: Metropolis CurCost : " + this.getCur_cost(),"notification");
                          LogTool.print("SolveSA Cost delta " + (Cur_cost - New_cost) + " ","notification");
                   }
                          Cur_state = New_state;
                          Cur_cost = New_cost;

                    } else if (Math.exp(-(Cur_cost - New_cost)/temperature)> random_double) {

                        Cur_state = New_state;
                        Cur_cost = New_cost;

                        if (Config.SAdebug) {
                            LogTool.print("SolveSA: NewCost : " + this.getNew_cost(),"notification");
                            LogTool.print("SolveSA: CurCost : " + this.getCur_cost(),"notification");
                        }

                        if (Config.SAverboselvl>1) {
                            LogTool.print("Fall 2: Zufallsgenerierter Zustand traegt hoehere Kosten als vorhergehender Zustand. Iteration: " + x,"notification");
                        }
                    }

               temperature = temperature-1;
               if (temperature==0)  {
                   break;
               }

               random_double = RandGenerator.randDouble(0.01, 0.99);
               newState();
               setNew_cost(cost());
            }

            if (ab==9) {
                double diff=0;
            }

//This is where the trouble happens - GlobalLoewst cost is set correctly and kept throughout the loops, GLowestState is always the last value of Cur_State (the most recent completed iteration. If smoothly running, that would be iteration 9 and inner iteration 99) @stackexchange

            if (Cur_cost<Global_lowest_cost) {
                this.setGlobal_lowest_cost(Cur_cost);
                GlobalState GLowestState = new GlobalState(this.Cur_state);
                LogTool.print("GLS DEDICATED OBJECT STATE OUTPUT  -- " + GLowestState.getGlobal_Lowest_state_string(),"notification");
                this.setGlobal_Lowest_state(GLowestState.getDwelltimes());
                LogTool.print("READ FROM OBJECT OUTPUT  -- " + this.getGlobal_Lowest_state_string(),"notification");
//                LogTool.print("DEBUG: CurCost direct : " + this.getCur_cost(),"notification");        
//                LogTool.print("Debug: Cur<global CurState get : " + this.getCur_state_string(),"notification");
//                LogTool.print("Debug: Cur<global GLS get : " + this.getGlobal_Lowest_state_string(),"notification");
//                this.setGlobal_Lowest_state(this.getCur_state(Cur_state));
//                LogTool.print("Debug: Cur<global GLS get after set : " + this.getGlobal_Lowest_state_string(),"notification");        
            }
            LogTool.print("SolveSA: Iteration : " + ab,"notification");
            LogTool.print("SolveSA: Last Calculated New State/Possible state inner loop 99 : " + this.getNew_state_string(),"notification");
//            LogTool.print("SolveSA: Best Solution : " + this.getCur_state_string(),"notification");
            LogTool.print("SolveSA: GLS after: " + this.getGlobal_Lowest_state_string(),"notification");
            LogTool.print("SolveSA: NewCost : " + this.getNew_cost(),"notification");
            LogTool.print("SolveSA: CurCost : " + this.getCur_cost(),"notification");        
        }
    }

=================

public final class GlobalState implements Comparable<Object>{
    private double[] dwelltimes;
    private static GlobalState instance = null;

    protected GlobalState(){
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation
    }

    public static GlobalState getInstance(){
        if (instance==null){
            instance = new GlobalState();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public GlobalState(double[] dwelltimes) {
        this.dwelltimes = dwelltimes;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public double[] getDwelltimes() {
        return dwelltimes;
    }

    public String getGlobal_Lowest_state_string() {
        String Global_Lowest_state_string = new String();
        for (int cc = 0; cc < Config.SAnumberOfSeeds; cc++) {
            Global_Lowest_state_string = Global_Lowest_state_string.concat(" " + cc + ") " + dwelltimes[cc]);
            }
        return Global_Lowest_state_string;
    }

    public void setDwelltimes(double[] dwelltimes_x) {
        this.dwelltimes = dwelltimes_x;
    }

}
```

Comment: The scope of `GLowestState` is limited to the solve() method currently.

Comment: How is my answer below Daniel? You need to use `public` attributes.

Comment: Id like to provide some more context. I originally had a field GlobalLowestState (GLS for brevity). I wrote to that field if a certain condition was met - this was checked inside the solve() method.

THe problem was that GLS took the value of the last computed Cur_State  instead of  the value of the globally lpowest state (which is what the check is for). I found no fault with the code so I had the globaly lowest value written into the object GLS instead of the field. Miraculously, the GLS object contained the CORRECT values. But it wasnt accessible outside of solver() class even with a get().

Answer (score 0):

If `GLowestState` is a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) then you really can't call `new` on it -- assuming it is a well implemented Singleton.

If it is well implemented then you call it like this:

```
GLowestState.getInstance();
```

Another example:

```
 GLowestState.getInstance().foo();
```

Comment: My code fails with a nullpointer exception. The way that you see below runs successfully and outputs --> GLS external: packagr.GlobalState@21533b2c (CTRL+K didnt work): BUt accessing the methods or fields within it fails. Why ?

    solver.solve();
    GlobalState GLSW = GlobalState.getInstance();
    LogTool.print("GLS external: " + GlobalState.getInstance(),"notification");

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this:

```
public class Solver {
    private GlobalState GLowestState;

    public void solve() {
        GLowestState = new GlobalState(this.Cur_state);
    }

    public GlobalState  getGLowestState() {
        return GLowestState;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `public GlobalState getGLowestState()`, with the type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Solver to be a singleton you need a private constructor and a newInstance method.
Create a field gloweststate and access it with a getter

```
public class run {
    //stuff
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //stuff
        Solver solver = Solver.getInstance().solve(body,seeds);
        LogTool.print("OUTPUT field of CLASS CREATED IN solver -- " + solver.getGLowestState(),"notification");
    }
}
===========
public class Solver {

    private GlobalState gLowestState;
    private static Solver singeltonSolver;

    private Solver() {

    }

    public synchronized static Solver getInstance(){
        if(singeltonSolver== null)
            singeltonSolver = new Solver();
         return singeltonSolver;
    }

    public void solve( SOmeType body,SOmeType seeds) {
        //stuff
        GlobalState GLowestState = new GlobalState(this.Cur_state);
    }

    public GlobalState getGLowestState() {
        return gLowestState;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java, at least, they're called fields, not properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `getter` for the object inside of your class, as well as made the variable an `instance variable`, rather than a `local variable`. For your code, an example is:

```
public class Solver {
    // stuff
    GlobalState GLowestState;

    public void solve() {
        // stuff
        GLowestState = new GlobalState(this.Cur_state);
    }
    public GlobalState getGLowestState(){
        return GLowestState;
    }
}
```

Notice how `GLowestState` now belongs to the instance of the class, rather than a local variable in the method `solve()`. You can now call

```
Solver solver = new Solver(body,seeds);
solver.solve();
GlobalState GS = solver.getGLowestState();
```

And the variable GS will continue the `GlobalState` variable for that particular instance of the `Solver` object.

Comment: This is what i originally wanted to implement. I used a getter to get a double[] of a field inside GlobalState. However GlobalState is not visible...

Comment: If you do not want to make `GlobalState` visible (which, since it is a separate class that you want to use outside of your `Solver` class, you should), you can change your method to get the details of the `GlobalState` object individually. For example, if you had an `int` and a `String` in `GlobalState`, you could make a `getGlobalStateString()` method to return the `String`, and `int` method for the `int`. Like I said though, it is good programming to create another class file and make it visible if it will be used outside the current class.

Comment: I implemented this yet i get a nullpointerexception when trying to eead solver.getGLowestState. i think either the object is destroyed when solveSA finishes .. Or idk...

Comment: @DanielStuart Can you update your question with your entire code? It is hard for me to tell where you got an Exception without having the code, or at least a stack trace. In your call `solver.getGLowestState()`, the only thing that would cause a NPE in that line is if `solver` is `null`. If that was the case, you are then calling `null.getGLowestState()`, and trying to call a function on a `null` object always causes a NPE.

Comment: it is around 600 lines in three files. how do I best put it up here ?
Oh and you need several libraries one of them is also by my team.

Comment: Add the important portions. The code around where the NPE happens, the objects, the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to have `GlobalState` hold the Singleton.

```
public enum GlobalState {
    INSTANCE;

    public String getValue() { ... }
}
```

However, it is better that the `Solver` retain its state and not mess with global state.

```
public class Solver {
    final String field;
    //stuff
    public Solver(int body, int seeds) {
        //solve stuff here
        this.field = "value";
    }
}

public class Run {
    //stuff
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //stuff
        Solver solver = new Solver(body,seeds);
        LogTool.print("OUTPUT field of " + solver.field);
   }
}
```

Comment: I read that using enum is, well, bad style for implementing thek singleton. Why did you use it?

Answer (score 0):

It could be accomplisched in many ways :

1- If `GlowestState` is particularly related to `solve()` only then return it and use that returned object.

```
 public GlobalState solve() {
    GlobalState globalState = new GlobalState(this.Cur_state);
    return globalState;
}
```

Now you can access it as :

```
Solver solver = new Solver(body,seeds);
GlobalState globalState = solver.solve();
```

2- Make `GlowestState` an instance and make it public.

```
public GlobalState glowestState;
public void solve() {
    GLowestState = new GlobalState(this.Cur_state);
}
```

Then you can get it by calling solver.glowestState

3- Use a getter to get `GLowestState`.

```
private GlobalState glowestState;
public void solve() {
    glowestState = new globalState(this.Cur_state);
}

public getGlowestState() {
    return GLowestState;
}
```

Now you can get it by calling `getGlowestState()`